# Can I apply same data source for kendo grid and chart without using shared datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid and chart in my application.I am using shared data source for both grid and chart.But i want to use same datasource for both grid and chart without using shared datasource.I want to bind the result of grid as chart datasource.Is it possible?If it is possible how to do that?If any one know about this please help me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you do not want to use shared dataSource then you have to use different dataSource with the same configuration object. I guess you are trying to stay [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

To do so you can use the same configuration object in both places. 
e.g.

```
var configDS = {
                        type: "odata",
                        transport: {
                            read: "..."
                        },
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                fields: {
                                    ...
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        pageSize: 20,
                        serverPaging: true,
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        serverSorting: true
                    }

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
       dataSource: configDS 
       //other options for Grid
  })
$('#chart').kendoChart({
       datasource:configDS
      //other options for Chart
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.I am also using like this,but my application has huge amount of data so my application get struked. That is my problem.so i want to bind the little amount of data and chart. why it is stuked?

Comment: I did not understand that, please clarify.

Comment: In my application i am also using data source like above you mentioned.But In my page load i had displaying 100(out of20000 )records in grid and chart,when we apply filtering data is filtered then we click the clear button all the data(20000) records are dispalying in chart and grid,then my apllication is struked

Comment: And what is the question? Just use less data for the chart or always apply some filter to its dataSource so you use less number of records.